# Excel VBA "Autofill Method of Range Class Failed"

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, autofill

The following VBA code (Excel 2007) is failing with Error 1004, "Autofill Method of Range Class Failed.".  Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

```
Dim src As Range, out As Range, wks As Worksheet

Set wks = Me
Set out = wks.Range("B:U")
Set src = wks.Range("A6")
src.AutoFill Destination:=out
```

(note: I have Googled, etc. for this.  It comes up fairly often, but all of the responses that I saw had to do with malformed range addresses, which AFAIK is not my problem.

---

At someone's suggestion I tried replacing the autofill line with the following:

```
src.Copy out
```

This had the effect of throwing my Excel session into an apparent infinite loop consuming 100% CPU and then just hanging forever.

---

OK, apparently the source has to be part of the destination range for autofill.  So my code now looks like this:

```
Dim src As Range, out As Range, wks As Worksheet

Set wks = Me
Set out = wks.Range("B1")
Set src = wks.Range("A6")
src.Copy out

Set out = wks.Range("B:U")
Set src = wks.Range("B1")
src.AutoFill Destination:=out, Type:=xlFillCopy
```

Same error on the last line.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb209671.aspx):

> The destination must include the
>   source range.

`B:U` does not contain `A6` and thus there is an error. I believe that you probably want `out` to be set to `A6:U6`.

Specifiying just the column name means that you want to fill every row in that column which is unlikely to be the desired behvaiour

---

**Update**

Further to the OP's comment below and update to the original answer, this might do the trick:

```
Dim src As Range, out As Range, wks As Worksheet

Set wks = Me
Set out = wks.Range("B1")
Set src = wks.Range("A6")
src.Copy out

Set out = wks.Range("B1:U1")
Set src = wks.Range("B1")
src.AutoFill Destination:=out, Type:=xlFillCopy

Set out = wks.Range("B:U")
Set src = wks.Range("B1:U1")
src.AutoFill Destination:=out, Type:=xlFillCopy
```

`AutoFill` is constrained to a single direction (i.e. horizontal or vertical) at once. To fill a two-dimensional area from a single cell you first have to auto-fill a line along one edge of that area and then stretch that line across the area

For the specific case of copying the formatting and clearing the contents (by virtue of the source cell being empty), this is better:

```
Dim src As Range, out As Range, wks As Worksheet

Set wks = Sheet1
Set out = wks.Range("B:U")
Set src = wks.Range("A6")
src.Copy out
```

Comment: Actually, I ***am*** trying to reset the formating(to whats in A6) and clear the contents for all rows in that column range.  This works fine when I do it manually.

Answer (score 4):

To make `AutoFill` work, you need to make the range of `AutoFill` more than the *source range*. If the AutoFill range is same as of Source range then there is nothing to AutoFill in that range and hence you would get an error

> 1004: AutoFill method of Range class failed.

So make AutoFill range more than the source range and error will gone.

Comment: Thanks, but that was not the problem in this case.  You will note from my code that the source was one cell, whereas the out range was several columns.

Comment: MSDN says "...destination must include ... source..." If Source = Destination, then Destination does indeed include Source in the sense that every element (row) of Source is, of course, in Destination. Let set S consist of all rows in Source. Let set D consist of all rows in Destination. Then S is a subset of D. But also D is a subset of S. We say that S is an **improper** subset of D and code based on this "model" is also improper. A **proper** subset of D can be made by removing one or more rows from S. Code based on this "model" is also proper.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to autofill you just do something like...

```
Private Sub Autofill()

'Select the cell which has the value you want to autofill
Range("Q2").Select

'Do an autofill down to the amount of values returned by the update
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Q2:Q10")

End Sub
```

This would autofill down to the specified range.

Does ths help?

Comment: How does this differ from what I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps anyone, but I needed something similar.  Selecting the cells as destination works;

```
dim rowcount as integer
Sheets("IssueTemplate").Select ' Whatever your sheet is
rowcount = 0
rowcount = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))'get end range
Cells(4, 3).Select 'select the start cell
'autofill to rowcount
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C4:C" & rowcount), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

in my example I had to auto-generate a list of folder names from OA100 to OA###?, and this worked fine.