# AutoFill method of range class failed, what am I missing?

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I'm trying to auto fill a row of formulas to the row before it.

I'm on excel 2010. I know that the ranges I'm using in the autofill function are the right ranges, I checked by adding in the select function and going line by line to make sure it selected the right ones.

```
Sub NewIC()

Dim v As Range, newV As Range, oldVRow As Range, newVRow As Range
Dim s As Range
Dim dc As Range

With Sheets("Charts").Cells
    'Inserting name into Vios
    Set v = .Find("Vios", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not v Is Nothing Then
        v.Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(4, 0).Select

        With Selection.EntireRow.Insert(xlShiftDown, xlFormatFromRightOrBelow)
            Set newV = ActiveCell
            Range("T1").Copy newV
            newV.Font.Bold = True
        End With
    End If

    'Dragging up formulas
    Set oldVRow = Range(newV.Offset(-1, 1), newV.Offset(-1, 8))
    Set newVRow = Range(newV.Offset(0, 1), newV.Offset(0, 8))
    oldVRow.Select
    newVRow.Select

    newVRow.AutoFill Destination:=oldVRow, Type:=xlFillDefault
End With

End Sub
```

All of the code works up until the last line. It sets the right cell as newV, sets the right ranges, but I get the error

> Run-time error '1004' AutoFill method of Range class failed

Comment: The destination has to include the origin. From the look of your `Offset`s, I don't think `newVRow` and `oldVRow` overlap.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA "Autofill Method of Range Class Failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528800/excel-vba-autofill-method-of-range-class-failed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify:

```
Set newVRow = Range(newV.Offset(0, 1), newV.Offset(0, 8))
```

to include the row above:

```
Set newVRow = Range(newV.Offset(-1, 1), newV.Offset(0, 8))
```

and change:

```
newVRow.AutoFill Destination:=oldVRow, Type:=xlFillDefault
```

to:

```
oldVRow.AutoFill Destination:=newVRow, Type:=xlFillDefault
```

You don't need to use all this `Select`:

```
'oldVRow.Select  ' comment this row
'newVRow.Select  ' comment this row
```