# Autofill cells based on drop down list in excel

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I am trying to creata a VBA that gives me automatic values based on drop down list in a form. The problem is that when I run the macro then it is causing an error and excel stops working. Any help in this case is most welcome.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("$G$11") = "UD Sheet" Then
        Rows("20:25").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("21:25").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

If Range("G12").Value = "Flex Tape" Then
        Range("B20").Value = "None"
    Else
        Range("B20").Value = ""
    End If
exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please post the whole routine, what is the Event that you're using for this one? Target is a range object so I think you are calling this via an Event.

Comment: Yes, basically there is a data validation in "Cell G12" which when clicked fills in values in Cells "B20:R20" but currently I am trying to use it with autofill formula which is also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first, in your code, no need to put an Exit Sub before the End Sub. 
The code will end after that line so this is a redundancy.

The next thing that you need to understand is that the Change Event will keep triggering if you will not disable it explicitly. So it means that when you hide a row on that Sheet, the Change Event will keep on happening since there will be  changes that will happen on the Sheet. i.e. (Hiding Rows).

To do that you need to disable the EventsListeners of the application using the Application.EnableEvents = False. So the application can do a single thing based on that first event.

The next thing that you need to keep in mind is to track where the Changes occur and fire your program. Target is a Range Object that will return the Range where the specific change occurs on the Sheet.

In order to do that, you need to validate if you need to trigger the routine based on the target using the Intersect function.

The whole code is as follows:

```
     Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     Application.EnableEvents = False

     If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G11")) Is Nothing Then
         If Range("$G$11") = "UD Sheet" Then    
             Rows("20:25").EntireRow.Hidden = False
         Else
             Rows("21:25").EntireRow.Hidden = True
         End If
     End If

     If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G12")) Is Nothing Then
         If Range("G12").Value = "Flex Tape" Then
             Range("B20").Value = "None"
         Else
             Range("B20").Value = ""
         End If
     End If
     Application.EnableEvents = True
     End Sub
```

Comment: ````
If Range("G12").Value = "Flex Tape" Then
        Range("'Product names'!B9:G9").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B20:R20"), Type:=xlFillCopy
    Else
        Range("B20:R20").ClearContents
    End If
````

Comment: I tried to do this with the autofill formula in this case since there are more than 1 cells that needs to be filled in when I select the drop down menu but there is no change in the XL sheet

Comment: Ah, Understood. I tried your way and it is working but in this case, the idea is to fill up multiple cells. For example, B20=X, E20=XX, H20=X and so on. So my question is will simply adding multiple ranges in the formula would work or do I need to trigger the routine everytime?

Comment: I see, Try to use the Copy method instead of the Autofill method Range("B9:G9").Copy Destination:=Range("B20:R20") Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528800/excel-vba-autofill-method-of-range-class-failed for the explanation.