# AutoFill method of range class failed '1004'

Tags: excel, vba

Am adding a line to an Excel table and I created a macro that fill down line from G to L to apply formula on new line.

```vb
Private Sub AutofillNewRows(ByRef modifiedRows As Collection)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
    Set modifiedRows = New Collection
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim startColumn As Long
    Dim endColumn As Long
    Dim isRowEmpty As Boolean
    
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    
    

    startColumn = 7 ' Column G
    endColumn = 12 ' Column L
    
    ' Find last used row in column G
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).row

    ' Loop through each row from bottom to the first row of data
    For row = lastRow To 4 Step -1 ' Assuming row 4 is headers
        isRowEmpty = False
        For col = startColumn To endColumn ' Columns G to L
            If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(row, col)) Then
                isRowEmpty = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next col
        
        If isRowEmpty Then
            ' Fill down the formulas for the range G:L from the row above
            
            Call AutoFillWithCopyMethod(ws, row)
            
            ' Add the row number to the collection
            modifiedRows.Add row
                        
            
            ' HN Handling
            ws.Cells(row, "HN").Formula = "=IF(ISNA(MATCH($A" & row & ",$A$3:$A" & row - 1 & ",0)),1,0)"
        End If
    
    Next row
End Sub
```

```vb
Sub AutoFillWithCopyMethod(ws As Worksheet, row As Long)
    ' Construct the range address as a string
    Dim sourceRangeAddress As String
    Dim destinationRangeAddress As String
    
    sourceRangeAddress = "G" & (row - 1) & ":L" & (row - 1)
    destinationRangeAddress = "G" & row & ":L" & row
    
    ' Perform the copy operation using the range addresses
    ws.Range(sourceRangeAddress).AutoFill Destination:=ws.Range(destinationRangeAddress), Type:=xlFillDefault

    
    ' If you want to only copy formulas without formatting or data validation
    ' ws.Range(destinationRangeAddress).Formula = ws.Range(sourceRangeAddress).Formula
End Sub
```

the problem is in this line : `ws.Range(sourceRangeAddress).AutoFill Destination:=ws.Range(destinationRangeAddress), Type:=xlFillDefault`

I tried passing the range as String because when I record the macro it does work and the parameters are passed as strings, but still getting error.

But when I change AutoFill to Copy it works.

Comment: Two issues I'm seeing: A) Why pass the variable `modifiedRows` if you're going to set it as a new Collection? B) If you want to Autofill empty cells with the above formula, why loop backwards? You could encounter two empty cells above one another and then have no formula in the lowest one.

Comment: frgt to mention t ignore the variable modifiedRows it's used elsewhere. I loop backward to avoid the issue you mentionned, because the last line is guaranteed to be filled.

Comment: When i use copy it works fine, i don't see where is the problem with my code in the second function

Comment: If the last line is guaranteed, you'd need to fill upwards as well, no? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1528853/19353309) mentions needing the source range be part of the destination range. Try `sourceRangeAddress = "G" & (row + 1) & ":L" & (row + 1) 'since it's always got a result in backwards loop
    destinationRangeAddress = "G" & row & ":L" & row+1`

Comment: Thank you that did it even tho I don't know why ! your comment should be an answer because this problem is really confusing and time consuming

Comment: You're welcome, I glossed over it being necessary as well when I checked the documentation at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're looping backwards because you have a guaranteed filled line at the end, you'd want your source range to be the below row, not the above one.

The issue for your error was not including the source range in the destination range, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1528853/19353309)

Your second sub should look like this:

```
Sub AutoFillWithCopyMethod(ws As Worksheet, row As Long)
    ' Construct the range address as a string
    Dim sourceRangeAddress As String
    Dim destinationRangeAddress As String
    
    sourceRangeAddress = "G" & (row + 1) & ":L" & (row + 1)
    'the brackets aren't necessary as shown below:
    destinationRangeAddress = "G" & row & ":L" & row+1
    
    ' Perform the copy operation using the range addresses
    ws.Range(sourceRangeAddress).AutoFill Destination:=ws.Range(destinationRangeAddress), Type:=xlFillDefault

    
    ' If you want to only copy formulas without formatting or data validation
    ' ws.Range(destinationRangeAddress).Formula = ws.Range(sourceRangeAddress).Formula
End Sub
```

If you're not going to use the collection values and just going to set it as a new collection, you're better off declaring a new one or making it a Public one (between Option Explicit and the first sub) in case you will use the new collection in another sub.